# Environment–patching vs. non–environment–patching webshims in open source node modules

Tags: node-modules, webshim

## Short version

Would you, as a web app developer, be OK with a gadget or a library that requires some ES5 shims like [these](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) for it to work in IE7&8? How about if it included these shims itself, thus patching your global JavaScript?

## Long version

When writing an open source node module that is meant to be run also in old browsers like IE7 and IE8, where should I "get" my ES5 `Array.prototype.forEach`, `Object.keys` and such?

Should I rely on environment–patching shims (like like https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) or non–environment–patching shims (like https://www.npmjs.org/package/lodash.keys)?

The original issue [is this](https://github.com/eugeneware/changeset/pull/5#issuecomment-58983278).

I supplied my own answer to this but it is inconclusive. I would like to ask:

1. What is the standard for this? Is there a common policy?
2. Are there performance implications that are meaningful?
3. What other upsides and downsides have I not included in my answer?
4. Are there module maintenance considerations I have not taken into account?

Answer (score 0):

### Environment–patching shims

Shims like https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim "monkey-patch a JavaScript context to contain all EcmaScript 5 methods that can be faithfully emulated with a legacy JavaScript engine", thus allowing me to write my module with some of the ES5 methods.

#### Downsides

1. My module code is simpler (`[1, 2, 3].forEach(function(){});`).

#### Upsides

1. I must include shims in my testing setup, if I'm testing in those browsers that need them.
2. I "force" my module's consumers to rely on shims.

### Non–environment–patching shims"

Or, "non–shims" like [`lodash.keys`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/lodash.keys) or [`foreach`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/foreach), can be used.

#### Upsides

1. I don't need to use shims in my tests.
2. I don't "force" my module's consumers to use shims.

#### Downsides

1. My module's code is less pretty, like

   ```
   var forEach = require("foreach");
   forEach([1, 2, 3], function(){});
   ```

   And I can't use as a method, which negates possibility of chaining.